# why prolog isn't printing this list

Tags: list, search, printing, prolog, items

I have  a prolog rule  below

```
schedule(mary,[ma424,ma387,eng301]).
```

and I have a predicate

```
taking(X,Y):- schedule(X, [Y | L]).
```

and when I try to figure out what  classes she's taking by  typing

```
taking(mary,Y).
```

i'm getting
y=ma424

**why  isn't it printing out ALL of her classes**

i've also tried this and other variation

```
taking(X,Y):- schedule(X,[X|L]),schedule(Y, [Y | L]),schedule(Y,L),X\=Y,X\=L.
```

but  it doesnt work

how  do I get it to print  all the classes give the way my rule is defined

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the way you defined the predicate.

```
taking(X,Y) :-        % X takes class Y if...
    schedule(X,       % in the schedule for X,
             [Y|L]).  % Y is the first element.
```

Your program will not magically decide to search through the list `L` if you don't tell it to. To do that, use the `member/2` predicate:

```
taking(Student, Class) :-
    schedule(Student, Classes),
    member(Class, Classes).
```